# aspectj with android, aspect never called

Tags: android, android-studio, aspectj

In the project I'm working we've recently added some level of security, now i don't want to have to rewrite the entire nework logic if it can be done much more easily with AOP.

So, I'm trying to intercept the "onRequestSuccess" method of the requestListeners that are used throughout the application.
For this I have made a simple aspect:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


@Aspect
public class NetworkResponseAspect {

@Around("execution(public void *.onRequestSuccess(..))")
public void intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
    System.out.println("call intercepted " + joinPoint);


    try {
        joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("wut");
    }

}
```

}

I've added the aspectj weaver dependency: compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6'

And it seems to work, at least the annotations are recognized by android studio.

I've placed a breakpoint on the "joinpoint.proceed()" call and started the application in debug mode.
But when I log in (an action that triggers one such listener) nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: In my case also `@Before` and `@After` are getting callbacks but `@Around`

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you would use AspectJ Maven Plugin (current version is 1.7), in Gradle something similar. This is what you need for compilation if you want to use CTW (compile-time weaving). Those plugins should already contain a dependency on *aspectjtools.jar* which contains the AspectJ compiler and other stuff. If you use CTW, you need *aspectjrt.jar* (AspectJ runtime) as a default-scoped (compile) or dependency because it is needed during runtime as well.

If you want to use load-time weaving (LTW), though, you need *aspectjweaver.jar* on your JVM command line via `-javaagent:...` because the weaving agent needs to hook into class-loading before your first application class is loaded. P.S.: The weaving agent also contains the AspectJ runtime classes, so you do not need an additional dependency on the runtime in this case.

Comment: I'm indeed using gradle for my project but apart from the separate libs I can't seem to find an actual plugin. 
I do believe CTW is the way to go here so I tried using the runtime tools in stead of the weaver lib but unfortunately it made no difference.
The only promising thing i found was this project: https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj
I guess I'll give that a try

Comment: Yes, that plugin name rings a bell. (I am a Maven guy, not a Gradle one, but I think I used the plugin once in order to answer another question. I would have to get home in order to access my home PC though, I am still on the road.) If you want to use CTW you definitely need to compile the aspect using a plugin utilising the AspectJ compiler. Javac is not enough for CTW. And you definitely need the dependency on *aspectjrt.jar*.